# Sql to Rails Query association, joins and order_by

Tags: mysql, join, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, rails-activerecord

I want to convert a sql query to rails query

SQL:

`select count(*),`created_at`from subscriptions where`account_id`= (select id from`accounts`where`google_domain`IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY`created_at`ORDER BY`created_at`DESC;`

i tried this but am not getting exact result.

My partial solution::

```
Subscription.joins(:account).where('accounts.google_domain is not null').count
```

Here i don't know how to use group and order by.

If any information needed just give a comment. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subscription.joins(:account).order("your need").group("Your need").where("accounts.google_domain IS NOT NULL").count

Hope this will help to you